# Why does async slow down independent, subsequent code?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a method, triggered by my UI thread, that loads some data. The data is not needed immediately by the UI thread. Most of the data comes from databases, some part is read from file. After making the database read asynchronous, the file reading slowed down.

This is how my original load method looks like:

```
public void load() {
  var sw = new Stopwatch();

  sw.Start();
  db1.loadDB();
  sw.Stop();
  Console.WriteLine("DB1: " + sw.Elapse.Milliseconds);

  sw.Restart();
  db2.loadDB();
  sw.Stop();
  Console.WriteLine("DB2: " + sw.Elapse.Milliseconds);

  sw.Restart();
  db3.loadDB();
  sw.Stop();
  Console.WriteLine("DB3: " + sw.Elapse.Milliseconds);

  sw.Restart();
  file.loadFile();
  sw.Stop();
  Console.WriteLine("File: " + sw.Elapse.Milliseconds);
}
```

Because each of the database loadDB methods executes multiple database queries, I thought it might be a good idea to implement them asynchronously.

```
public void load() {
  var sw = new Stopwatch();

  sw.Start();
  taskDB1 = db1.loadDBAsync();
  sw.Stop();
  Console.WriteLine("DB1: " + sw.Elapse.Milliseconds);

  sw.Restart();
  taskDB2 = db2.loadDBAsync();
  sw.Stop();
  Console.WriteLine("DB2: " + sw.Elapse.Milliseconds);

  sw.Restart();
  taskDB3 = db3.loadDBAsync();
  sw.Stop();
  Console.WriteLine("DB3: " + sw.Elapse.Milliseconds);

  sw.Restart();
  file.loadFile();
  sw.Stop();
  Console.WriteLine("File: " + sw.Elapse.Milliseconds);
}
```

The tasks are awaited in another method, that is called when the UI thread actually needs the data.

What bothers me about this is the time it takes the loadFile method to execute. Before the asynchronous implementation of the loadDB they each took about 100ms to complete, while the loadFile method took about 20ms to complete. The asynchronous implementation of loadDBAsync takes approximately 5ms to complete. But in the second example the loadFile method takes 50ms to complete. I didn't change the loadFile method at all.

How is it possible, that the async database access slows down reading the file?

Edit:
Added the code I used to measure timings.
The database is on the same disk, at least for now. The 5ms are to submit the task.

Comment: if your db is on the same disk as the file.. you could suffer from IO bottleneck.. are you sure your loadDBAsync only took 5ms, or it took 5ms to submit the task..

Comment: First of all: How did you measure these timings? That is already an important part of the analysis. And second: Be aware that your CPU still has to do all the same work, and the IO work also is still the same. What is different when making the DB calls async is just the moment in time when this happens. So you need to think about what should happen when to get optimal performance.

Comment: Please show us the code you used to perform the measurement calcs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does async slow down independent, subsequent code?

The code isn't independent.

It shares a slow resource with the concurrently-executing asynchronous code: the physical disk.

Your file read is slower because the disk is simultaneously reading data.

Note that if you have a non-scalable database, there's usually no point in making your database operations concurrent. All you're going to do is cause disk thrashing, and very likely end up taking *longer*. With a good SSD, you might break even, but it's almost impossible for concurrent database access to be *faster*.

Answer (score 1):

As [BugFinder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/687262/bugfinder) mentioned in his comment, you are probably hitting the IO bottleneck.

In the first case, you wait until all the DB operations are completed before accessing the file.

In the second, you have, potentially, up to four threads accessing the disk, most likely different sectors, simultaneously. So you have to spin the disk each time there's a thread context switch, and there could be many of those.

Try to:

```
public async Task load()
{
    //all your DB access logic as previously

    await Task.WhenAll(new [] { taskDB1, taskDB2, task DB3 });

    file.loadFile();
}
```

I guess, you will have `loadFile` performance comparable to the first version.

Comment: I agree that this is most likely the problem, but I don't want to wait for the database operations to complete in this method. Executing the file read before the database operations seems to fix the problem.

Comment: @Cedric OK, just make clear it in your question that you are looking for a solution, because you ask 'why is it slow', not 'how to make it faster', and BugFinder's comment + my answer pretty much cover the topic.